# ELMAH generates errors in quick succession

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In our intranet there are some clinks with href pointing to my applcation.  When any of the links is clicked and browser redirects, ELMAH generates the hundreds of repeating errors below for 10 seconds or so .

```
System.Web.HttpException: Server cannot set status after HTTP headers have been sent.
Generated: Tue, 13 Dec 2016 17:20:43 GMT

System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Server cannot set status after HTTP headers have been sent.
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.set_StatusCode(Int32 value)
   at System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorAttribute.OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeExceptionFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, Exception exception)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
```

My application has the following code in the Application_BeginRequest() and Application_Error() which set statuscode.  I am not sure if it has anything to do with it.

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)    {
      Response.BufferOutput = true;

      //enforce HTTPS
      if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal && !Request.IsSecureConnection )
      {
        bool addHttpsAttribute = true;
        foreach (Filter filter in GlobalFilters.Filters)
        {
          if (filter.Instance is RequireHttpsAttribute)
          {
            addHttpsAttribute = false;
            break;
          }
        }

        if (addHttpsAttribute)
          GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
      }
}

    protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      Response.BufferOutput = true;
      var httpContext = HttpContext.Current;

      var currentRouteData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(new HttpContextWrapper(httpContext));
      var currentController = " ";
      var currentAction = " ";

      if (currentRouteData != null) {
        if (currentRouteData.Values["controller"] != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentRouteData.Values["controller"].ToString())) {
          currentController = currentRouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
        }

        if (currentRouteData.Values["action"] != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentRouteData.Values["action"].ToString())) {
          currentAction = currentRouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
        }
      }

      var ex = Server.GetLastError();

      var controller = new myApp.Controllers.ErrorController();
      var routeData = new RouteData();
      var action = "OtherError";

      if (ex is HttpException) {
        var httpEx = ex as HttpException;

        switch (httpEx.GetHttpCode()) {
          case 404:
            action = "NotFound";
            break;

            // others if any

          default:
            action = "OtherError";
            break;
        }
      }

      httpContext.ClearError();
      httpContext.Response.Clear();
      httpContext.Response.StatusCode = ex is HttpException ? ((HttpException) ex).GetHttpCode() : 500;
      httpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
      routeData.Values["controller"] = "Error";
      routeData.Values["action"] = action;

      controller.ViewData.Model = new myApp.Models.HandleErrorInfo(ex, currentController, currentAction);
      ((IController) controller).Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(httpContext), routeData));

      Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code to observe the behaviour?

Comment: `Response.Clear` doesn't clear Http Headers, so this error can be expected most likely.

Comment: yes, but when I use my account to interact with the app I don't get error.  Other users don't get errors either when try the 2nd time.

Comment: so should I remove the line with HttpContext.Response.Clear()?

Comment: Try adding `HttpContext.Response.ClearHeaders()` and see if that helps.